# PHP Cookie vs Session variables

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-variables

I am modifying a login script from php-login.net and trying to make it more secure. This particular login script has a login class that sets both cookie and session variables when the user logs in.

```
/**
 *  write user data into PHP SESSION [a file on your server]
 */
   $_SESSION['user_name'] = $result_row->user_name;
   $_SESSION['user_email'] = $result_row->user_email;
   $_SESSION['user_logged_in'] = 1;

/**
 *  write user data into COOKIE [a file in user's browser]
 */
   setcookie("user_name", $result_row->user_name, time() + (3600*24*100));
   setcookie("user_email", $result_row->user_email, time() + (3600*24*100));
   $this->user_is_logged_in = true;
```

The unfortunate part is that on the page the user gains access to, nobody wrote a check to make sure the user was logged in when they got to that page. So if a person just types in the URL directly, they would not have to be logged in.

I want to know the best way to verify that the user has logged in. Currently, I am using this, but I do not know if it is redundant (meaning: will cookie variables always equal session variables, so there is no point in checking both?) Any input would be helpful.

```
session_start();
if(!(isset($_COOKIE['user_email']) && 
    isset($_SESSION['user_email']) &&
    ($_COOKIE['user_email']===$_SESSION['user_email']) &&
    isset($_COOKIE['user_name']) && 
    isset($_SESSION['user_name']) && 
    ($_COOKIE['user_name']===$_SESSION['user_name']) && 
    isset($login) && 
    $login->isUserLoggedIn())){
        header("location:../../index.php");
        exit;
     }
```

(Sorry for the poorly formatted code, I am still trying to figure out the nuances of text formatting on this site)

Comment: Wow. Just start from scratch.

Comment: Great Scott! I concur with @Relentless. However, if needing to go ahead with the pre-existing code I would suggest Session only checking. Scrap the cookie.

Comment: Yes, the cookie is redundant, there is already a cookie on the client side which points to the server side session variables.

Comment: Seconded. Just ditch the cookie and concentrate on better session management/class.

Comment: Sounds good, tossing the cookies. Thanks for the help. @PenguinCoder/@relentless, Unfortunately starting from scratch is not an option for this one. grumble, grumble.

Answer (score 2):

When using sessions there is already a cookie present with the session id which maps to a server side php session. All data you register there will be available in the global $_SESSION array. Storing the data in both the cookie aswell as on the server is normally pointless.

Only reason you would store the data in the cookie aswell is if you have more sites on the same domain name that need to share the cookie data.

Comment: So even if you want your users to be logged in after a few days/weeks after a few system restarts there's no need to commit data to the cookie? Do we need to set `session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"]` to a certain value to guarantee it stays there till the client clears browser history? Basically the question is, how do I make the client's browser remember my website and his logged in state when he comes back?

Comment: Well the session cookie lifetime is based on 2 tihngs. One part is the client side cookie, the other is the session lifetime and the garbage collection lifetime that's set in the php.ini file. Both will need to be set high if you want a long session duration.

Comment: I actually learnt that yesterday, about the garbage collector and changing the params in the ini file... I have that setup like that... just gotta keep an eye on the folder where the sessions are to see what happens and avoid storing too much info in there... if it starts to clutter too much I've already found a workaround with tokens and a database check. Although I won't use that to log anyone in, but probably just fill in some form fields. Thanks for the help^^

Comment: By the way, when having more sites in sub-domains, you could easily just set the session cookie domain to `.domain.com` and they'd serve every sub-domain. At least I think so from the documentation I went through => http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php#94961